# Minikube - access host machine's ports

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm using minikube with `hyperkit` driver, and I need to access a port opened on the host machine FROM a pod inside the minikube cluster.

There are 2 ways I can accomplish this:

### Port forwarding

Port forward of my local port to the `minikube ip`:

```
ssh -i $(minikube ssh-key) docker@$(minikube ip) -R 8080:localhost:8080
```

And then from the pod I can `curl 172.17.0.1:8080`

> source: https://medium.com/tarkalabs/proxying-services-into-minikube-8355db0065fd

### Local machine's IP

From my host machine, I get the minikube's bridge IP: `ifconfig bridge100`

```
bridge100: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether 8e:85:90:2d:d5:64
    inet 192.168.64.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.64.255
```

And then from the pod I can `curl 192.168.64.1:8080`

However, I'm not sure both methods are the right way.
Is there a way to statically reference the host machine to be able to access open ports.
What's the solution here?

Comment: Check out host networking at http://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/ not recommended to do so, as you will only have one pod with this networking with a given port open, but it's an option.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many layers of indirection involved here and you’ll have to inject the physical host’s IP address into the container as an environment variable or ConfigMap setting.  An ExternalName type Service could also work here.

The essential problem here is that each layer can find out about the layer immediately beyond it, but no further.  You have a host running a VM running a Kubernetes Pod.  The Pod can use the [downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) to find its Node’s IP address, but in your case that will be the VM and not the host around it.

(As a parallel question: you have an ordinary home router that’s 192.168.1.1, and your local system is 192.168.1.2.  You’re running some server on the router.  Meanwhile, you have a VM running on your local system, which sees the host as 172.17.0.1 and believes it is 172.17.0.2.  How does the VM reach the service on the router, if it doesn’t know about the 192.168.1.0/24 network in its local network environment?)

Answer (score 0):

For others that also reach this question trying to make a pod running in minikube access a port running on the host, please refer to this [reference](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/).

In summary:

1. Make sure the service in the host is bound to `0.0.0.0` (all IPs). If it is only `127.0.0.1` (localhost) this will not work.
2. The pod inside minikube needs to connect to the host `host.minikube.internal`.

Comment: Hi! What does it mean - "Make sure the service in the host is bound to 0.0.0.0 (all IPs)."? How to implement this and where?

Comment: Hi @GML-VS. In many languages, when you run a service, you specify something like `net.listen("localhost:8080")`. Instead, you should do `net.listen("0.0.0.0:8080")`.