# Not able to forward DB connection to host.minikube.internal

Tags: oracle, docker, kubernetes, minikube, portforwarding

**Problem**

I'm trying to forward an Oracle database connection to a pod on minikube. I'm using a `kubectl port-forward` command to connect from my local machine to Oracle successfully, and I'm trying to use the `host.minikube.internal` as I would use `localhost` on my local machine to try to connect to the database.

Essentially, `pod` -> `host.minikube.internal:1526` -> `localhost:1526` -> `Oracle DB: 1526`. However, when I try to run a query on the pod using this connection information, I receive the error: `ORA-12541: TNS:no listener`.

What should I do to connect?

**Context**

It previously worked using Docker Desktop. All the connection information and forwarding information worked the same, except I changed `host.docker.internal` to `host.minikube.internal` following some advice in the second answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164223/access-mysql-running-on-localhost-from-minikube) that pointed to this [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/) in minikube. I don't know why this simple swap would not work.

I'm on MacOS, Ventura 13.0 (22A380), using Kubernetes 1.26.1 and Minikube v1.28.0.

Comment: Perhaps this will lead me in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141656/minikube-access-host-machines-ports

Comment: Refer to Hugo Martin’s Essays on [Another Way of Accessing Host Resources in Minikube](https://hugomartins.io/essays/2021/09/another-way-of-accessing-host-resources-in-minikube/) and  also refer to (λx.x)eranga's Medium blog on how to [Replace Docker Desktop with Minikube and Hyperkit on macOS](https://medium.com/rahasak/replace-docker-desktop-with-minikube-and-hyperkit-on-macos-783ce4fb39e3), which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: It's actually not. Those guides seem useful, but I haven't figured out steps I could follow to solve this particular issue :/